# How do I kill a timed-out process in .net

Tags: .net

The code below is meant to execute an external process process from .net, and kill it if it does not terminate after a certain amount of time. The particular process used for testing just forever prints lines that say "y" on stdout.

The kill operation succeeds, however the process remains alive after that. To complicate matters, calling CancelOutputRead stops the output without producing the usual null at the end, so there is no clean way of knowing when the output is final (and can be processed).

I would like to know how to kill the process properly, and how to find out when it finished producing asynchronous output. Many thanks.

```
    use proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ()

    let processStartInfo = System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe", "-c yes")
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow <- true
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute <- false
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput <- true
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput <- false
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError <- true  

    let report (name:string) (value:System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs) : unit =
        let value = value.Data
        if value = null then
            printf "%s: NULL\n" name
        else
            printf "%s: %s\n" name value

    proc.StartInfo <- processStartInfo
    proc.OutputDataReceived.Add (report "stdout")
    proc.ErrorDataReceived.Add (report "stderr")
    if not (proc.Start ()) then
        failwithf "Could not start process"

    proc.BeginOutputReadLine ()
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine ()

    let res = proc.WaitForExit (100)
    printf "WaitForExit returned %O\n" res

    while not proc.HasExited do   
        proc.Kill ()

    printf "Waiting 10s\n"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 10000
    printf "Cancelling\n"
    proc.CancelErrorRead ()
    proc.CancelOutputRead ()
    printf "Done cancelling\n"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 3000
    ()
```

I get the following output:

```
WaitForExit returned False           // A higher timeout produces lots of "y" before here
stdout: y
Waiting 10s                          // kill has "succeeded" by now
stdout: y
stdout: y
stdout: y
stdout: y    
<thousands of "y" lines left out>
Cancelling                            // oh well, lets just stop listening if it won't die
Done cancelling
stdout: y                             // this is bad, I want to be processing the output now
```

Comment: That's not possible.  You probably just misinterpret what's going on, the process you started put thousands of "y" in the pipe buffer while you were sleeping.  You just need a long time to empty that buffer, the console doesn't scroll very fast.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I have replaced the prints with counters. I see 1.2 million lines in the first second and 15 million lines in the next 10s. The second number does not change if I kill the process after 200ms, so it is unlikely that I am just emptying a buffer filled by a long dead process. Also, the process shows up in task manager. I am still not seeing any nulls at the end, so cannot tell when it's safe to start processing the stored output without it changing underneath me. Thanks again.